# How to reset HashSet after Using retainAll method on it?

Tags: java, hashset

I have three HashSets with different people who have visited different countries. If I use Mexico.retainAll(Cuba); then Mexico.retainAll(Jamaica) It gives me the list of all people who have visited all three countries. Which are:
Olivia, John, William

But then when I do Mexico.retainAll(Cuba); then Mexico.removeAll(Jamaica), to only get people who have visited Mexico and Cuba but not Jamaica. It gives me an empty set?

The set values are the following:

```
HashSet<String> Mexico = new HashSet<String>();
```

[Olivia, Zoe, Jennifer, Susan, John, Isabella, William, Jack, Emma, Sophia]

```
HashSet<String> Cuba = new HashSet<String>();
```

[Olivia, Tom, Jennifer, Susan, John, William, Jack, Emma, Ava, Sophia, Lily]

```
HashSet<String> Jamaica = new HashSet<String>();
```

[Olivia, Tom, John, William, Ava, Jessica, Lily]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {   
    visitorPatternNOOP.allThreeCountries();
    visitorPatternNOOP.onlyMexicoCuba();
}


public class VisitorPatternNOOP {
    public void allThreeCountries (){
        Mexico.retainAll(Cuba);
        Mexico.retainAll(Jamaica);
        Iterator<String>  iterator = Mexico.iterator();
        System.out.println("These people has visited all three countries:  ");
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }

    public  void onlyMexicoCuba (){
        Mexico.retainAll(Cuba);
        Mexico.removeAll(Jamaica);
        Iterator<String> iterator = Mexico.iterator();
        System.out.println("These people have visited Mexico and Cuba Only: ");
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }
}
```

The output should have been [Jennifer, Susan, Jack, Emma, Sophia] but I am getting empty set.

Comment: Your methods are sharing the same set. You need to reset it in between, or keep it local to the methods.

Comment: Well yes, `retainAll` and `removeAll` modify the sets you call them on. If you don't want your original sets to be modified, you need to create a copy and work on that instead. The `HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c)` is useful here: `HashSet<String> copy = new HashSet<String>(Mexico); // Then call methods on copy`.

Comment: There's no magic reset button. You just have to repopulate it. Do whatever you did initially.

Comment: Thankyou I understand now

Answer (score 4):

`Mexico.retainAll` mutates the `Mexico` `Set`, so you can't call `allThreeCountries` followed by `onlyMexicoCuba`, and expect that `onlyMexicoCuba` will see the original content of the `Mexico` set.

You should generate a copy of the `Mexico` `Set`, and mutate that copy.

```
public void allThreeCountries (){
    HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<>(Mexico);
    result.retainAll(Cuba);
    result.retainAll(Jamaica);
    Iterator<String> iterator = result.iterator();
    System.out.println("These people has visited all three countries:  ");
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}

public  void onlyMexicoCuba (){
    HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<>(Mexico);
    result.retainAll(Cuba);
    result.removeAll(Jamaica);
    Iterator<String> iterator = result.iterator();
    System.out.println("These people have visited Mexico and Cuba Only: ");
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }
}
```